# Which plant is this?

Tags: identification, annuals

[image]

Which plant is this?
It has frosty leaves and white-pink flower and some purple underdeveloped flowers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'frosty' leaves, but the plant looks like a Petunia, specifically, a double flowered variety similar to the one pictured here https://www.bakker.com/en-gb/p/petunia-double-pirouette-pink-white-M58773. It'll only be that if you live somewhere warm and temperatures are over (roughly) 18deg C currently-these plants are grown as annuals for summer bedding here in the UK, and it's too early for them here yet. The leaves are not shiny and smooth, but are usually very slightly fuzzy to touch, but not majorly so.

Comment: They leaves have small white hairs. I live in India.